# How to add custom html, css and javascript in joomla 3 Article

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla

I am new at Joomla and want to add my own code into an article.
Normally i guess I just open the HTML Editor and put my code in but this is not working.
Joomla editor is dropping html tags and so on. Now I am confused.

I have try to search how can I do this but there are only incredible long articles and tutorials which are say: "First of all, install many, many extensions."

I cant believe that this is so complex to write some native html code in joomla.

Here is my example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #919191 0%, #f2f2f2 75%);
}

.container {
  background-color: #202020;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <label>Test</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
var containerItems = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
var containerFunction = function() {
  alert('Do something');
};
for (var i = 0; i < containerItems.length; i++) {
    containerItems[i].addEventListener('click', containerFunction, false);
}

</script>
</html>
```

When I run this website locally everything is find. Now I want to add this site in an existing joomla article.

What is the easiest way for this?

I also guess maybe an iFrame could be injected, but than there is the problem to host this website on the server.

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.

Comment: ...we'd still like to receive you and your question at JSE.  :)